Using spring boot app as artifact does not load properties neither dependencies
I need to create a spring boot app then generate Jar file so it will be used as an artifact.
This artifact is suposed to be an embedded spring mvc app where i have controllers and views.
Those views should be resolved by thymeleaf.
When I run this artifact as a standalone spring boot app it works fine.
So I generate the jar file (mvn clean install) which create a jar in my local repository.
In main spring boot apps I include this jar as dependency, but I have 2 issues:
1- application.properties defined in artifact do not load its properties.
2- dependencies defined in artifact pom.xml dont seem to be loaded (cant find org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafViewResolver in main app in intellij)
this is the artifact pom.xml :
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>dashboard</artifactId>
<version>0.0.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>projectname</name>

<description>some desc</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!-- Spring Boot Starter -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

Configuration class :
package com.example;
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "app.dashboard.enabled", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = true)
@Configuration
public class DashboardConfiguration {


    // adding view resolver to handle only artifact views
    @Bean
    public ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setPrefix("myfolder/templates/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine(ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver) {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver(SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine) {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine);
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        resolver.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        return resolver;
    }
}

and under main/resources folder I have :

myfolder/templates/ where I have views (index.html, login.html etc)
application.properties
META-INF/spring.factories where I defined

This is the content of application.properties :
app.dashboard.path=/convy
app.dashboard.username=convy
app.dashboard.password=vycon
app.dashboard.enabled=true

spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/convy/templates/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html

Basically I need th artifact to be used in other spring boot applications and its spring-boot-starter-web\spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf versions shoud be the one defined in main app or else 2.7.2 which is defined in the artifact pom.xml.
When this artifact is included in others apps with the right properties, a web page is exposed where i show some environement informations.

why using an out-of-date version of spring boot?

read about far jar, created via Maven shade plugin.
